# JavaFX how to show a text field only when a box is selected

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `JFXCheckBox` and I want that a `JFXTextField` is shown on the screen only when this `JFXCheckBox` is selected.

Is this possible? If not, what is the next solution?

Comment: Should put some of your code here so we know how to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

One line solution:

```
myTextField.visibleProperty().bind(myCheckBox.selectedProperty());
```

Comment: Welcome, don't forget accept the most suitable answer.

Comment: i realy would do if i can, but for do that apparently you need to have more than 15 respect, and i havent, but when possible i will come back and accept.

Comment: Some times when we bind a node we make it busy only with this binded node,for example you bind visibleProperty with selected property,it means we can not add other operation to visibility only if we remove the binding ,for this i think the listener is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can  add listener to selected property of CheckBox:

```
myCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                myTextField.setVisible(newValue);

        }
    });
```

Comment: A valid solution, but I don't see binding. I see listening.